# How to show the correct time to go?

Tags: javascript

I have set up this JS countdown timer and set the time to say my local time here in New Zealand,

```
CountDownTimer('01/31/2016 5:1 PM', 'countdown');
```

If someone in say Europe looks at the page, it says something like 20 hours to go, not 1 hour like in my local time.
How can I set it up that no matter where in the world, it will still show 1 hour to go?

Comment: Use server side logic for this. User machine can have invalid time. One can not depend on that..

Comment: Would you be able to help me with an example?
Thanks

Comment: what are you using on backend?

Answer (score 0):

If you could use Jquery you could make an `ajax` call on page load like below assign the server time to `js` variable and then process it as per your need.

```
$.ajax({
    url: location.href, 
    type:"get",
    data:"", 
    success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        alert("SERVER TIME: " + request.getResponseHeader('date'));
    }
});
```

Time returned is in GMT in above case. Look it up.
JS Alternative you could find here. http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?228309-Getting-server-date-time-with-no-server-side-script

Also if you are using any server side language you could fetch server time with Expression language or in jsp with scriptlets as well.